# Search a String in another array like string in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to make a query in mongodb for searching a string in another string. 
Now the use case is I have document like:

```
{
    "names":"[John,Mike,Stephen,Rock]"
}
```

Now I want to make a filter which will search for :

1. Case-1: If John is present in names or not
2. Case-2: If John and Mike both are present in this string

I am quite new to mongodb. I went through many posts, but I haven't got any satisfactory results as of now. Some are using regex or text search.Can anyone help in making the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below queries which uses regex pattern :

**Case 1 :** Check `names` string field contains a word `John`.

```
db.collection.find({ names: /John/})
```

**Case 2 :** Check `names` string field contains both `John` & `Mike` words.

```
db.collection.find({ names: {$all : [/John/, /Mike/]}})
```

I would suggest to have index on `names` field & try to use [text-search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/index.html) if possible.

**Ref :** [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/index.html)

Comment: whoami , how we can check the opposite that John is not present in names ? Can you help in that too . :)

Comment: @Anshul : You need to use `$nin` instead of `$all`. Something like this `db.collection.find({ names: {$nin : [/John/]}})`..

Comment: Ok , that works , thank you so much for the help !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the $in Operator to Match Values in an Array in MongoDb:

Suppose the collection inventory contains documents that include the field tags, as in the following:

```
{ _id: 1, item: "abc", qty: 10, tags: [ "school", "clothing" ]}
```

Then, the following find() operation will get tags field which holds an array with at least one element matching either "appliances" or "school".

```
db.inventory.find({ tags: { 
        $in: ["appliances", "school"] } 
});
```

For your use case 1:

```
db.users.find({names : "John"});
```

For your use case 2:

```
db.users.find({ names: { 
       $in: ["John", "Mike"]
 } });
```

Comment: But here its not the array its string, would searching using in will work in this case as well ?